# Buscar ip via sql

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird, tabela-banco-de-dados

Alguém sabe se existe uma forma de eu buscar via sql (firebird) todos os ips que estão utilizando uma Tabela ou Views?

Estou tentando atualizar uma view, porém estou tento o seguinte erro:

```
This operation is not defined for system tables. 
unsuccessful metadata update.
MinhaView.
Implementation of text subtype 65280 not located.
Changes will be rolled back...
```

Obs: Também não consigo deletar.

Obs: Se criar uma nova view, eu consigo gravar, porem não posso criar outra view e nem dar shutdown no banco.

Ou alguém tem outra ideia de como posso contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiago, o `Firebird` assim como em outros bancos possui tabelas internas para controles, através destas tabelas internas você consegue pegar as informações de conexões, transações e comandos executados, etc.

Utilize o seguinte `select` para pegar a informação que deseja e muito mais.

```
select
    A.MON$ATTACHMENT_ID as "Attachment ID",
    A.MON$SERVER_PID as "Server PID",
    A.MON$STATE as "State",
    A.MON$ATTACHMENT_NAME as "Attachment Name",
    A.MON$USER as "User",
    A.MON$ROLE as "Role",
    A.MON$REMOTE_PROTOCOL as "Remote Protocol",
    A.MON$REMOTE_ADDRESS as "Remote Address",
    A.MON$REMOTE_PID as "Remote PID",
    CS.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME as "Character Set",
    A.MON$TIMESTAMP as "Established At",
    A.MON$GARBAGE_COLLECTION as "Garbage Collection",
    A.MON$REMOTE_PROCESS as "Remote Process",
    A.MON$STAT_ID as "Statistics ID",
    ST.MON$STATEMENT_ID as "Statement ID",
    ST.MON$TRANSACTION_ID "Transaction ID",
    case
      when ST.MON$STATE = 0
        then
              'IDLE'
      when ST.MON$STATE = 1
        then
              'ACTIVE'
    end as "State",
    ST.MON$TIMESTAMP "Started At",
    ST.MON$SQL_TEXT "Statement Text",
    R.MON$RECORD_SEQ_READS as "Non-indexed Reads",
    R.MON$RECORD_IDX_READS as "Indexed Reads",
    R.MON$RECORD_INSERTS as "Records Inserted",
    R.MON$RECORD_UPDATES as "Records Updated",
    R.MON$RECORD_DELETES as "Records Deleted",
    R.MON$RECORD_BACKOUTS as "Records Backed Out",
    R.MON$RECORD_PURGES as "Records Purged",
    R.MON$RECORD_EXPUNGES as "Records Expunged",
    IO.MON$PAGE_READS as "Page Reads",
    IO.MON$PAGE_WRITES as "Page Writes",
    IO.MON$PAGE_FETCHES as "Page Fetches",
    IO.MON$PAGE_MARKS as "Page Marks"
from
    MON$ATTACHMENTS A
join MON$STATEMENTS ST on ST.MON$ATTACHMENT_ID = A.MON$ATTACHMENT_ID
join RDB$CHARACTER_SETS CS on (A.MON$CHARACTER_SET_ID = CS.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID)
left join MON$RECORD_STATS R on (A.MON$STAT_ID = R.MON$STAT_ID)
left join MON$IO_STATS IO on (A.MON$STAT_ID = IO.MON$STAT_ID)
where
    upper(ST.MON$SQL_TEXT) like upper(:PSQL) -- Comando SQL que deseja encontrar
    and
    ST.MON$STATE = 1 -- Para somente conexões ativas
```

No parâmetro do `select` você pode informar um SQL completo ou apenas uma parte.

Exemplo: `ST.MON$SQL_TEXT like '%USUARIO%'` ou `ST.MON$SQL_TEXT like 'select * from usuario where id =1'`.

O campo "Remote Address" é o IP da conexão que executou.

Agora se você estiver usando a ferramenta `IBExpert` você pode acessar o menu superior em Services > Database Monitoring, por lá consegue consultar essas informações e ainda derrubar uma determinada conexão.